# MASM - Printing a value from a procedure

Tags: assembly, masm

I have a program that I'm trying to work with using the stack and print values returned by `printf`, but I keep getting the wrong number. Sorry in advance, but I'm new to assembly.
The book I'm using does not explain it very well. Here's the code:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 100h

printf proto c arg1:ptr byte, printlist:vararg

.data


fmtmsg1 db "%d ",0

num1 dw 6 
num2 dw 7

.code
addvalues proc
      push ebp
      mov ebp,esp

      mov esi,[ebp + 12] ; number 6
      mov ecx,[ebp + 8] ; number 7

      mov ebx,dword ptr[esi]
      add ebx,dword ptr[ecx]

      invoke printf,addr fmtmsg1,ebx; print value

      pop ebp
      ret 8

addvalues endp


public main

main proc


     push offset num1 
     push offset num2
     call addvalues

     ret
main endp

end main
```

Comment: Change `dw` (e.g. in `num1 dw 6`) to `dd`.

Comment: thanks man but why dose this work and not dw instead

Comment: is it because every thing is offset by 4 in the stack 4 as in bytes is it always  by 4 in a stack frame thanks in advance

Comment: An instruction like `mov ebx,dword ptr[esi]` loads a DWORD (4 bytes). If you've reserved only 2 bytes (`dw` = "data word") it will load these two bytes **and** two bytes of the memory behind that, here from `num2`.